# How do I increase limits in my docker containers on CoreOS?

Tags: linux, coreos, systemd

By default, CoreOS and the Linux kernel has some pretty conservative limits defined for things such as open files and locked memory.

So I upped the values in /etc/systemd/system.conf:

```
DefaultLimitNOFILE=500000
DefaultLimitMEMLOCK=unlimited
```

However, when I start my docker containers the limits are still low. ulimit -l prints 64.

Running ulimit -l unlimited prints an error.

> ulimit: max locked memory: cannot modify limit: Operation not
>   permitted

So I placed

```
LimitMAXLOCKED=unlimited
LimitNOFILE=64000
```

In my systemd unit file.

However, these values are not coming through to the docker container and calling them still doesn't work.  I've rebooted the machine after changing the systemwide defaults.

This is probably more of a systemd thing.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Docker containers are not started nor managed by systemd. The Docker daemon is responsible for setting limits here. Here is an example taken from the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container-ulimit):

```
# docker run --ulimit nofile=1024:1024 --rm debian sh -c "ulimit -n"
```

Comment: From memory this didn't work on it's own.  As dockerd is a process like any other, you need to give permission to up the limit.  So I think I did both system wide limits then this and it did work.

Comment: As far as I remember, the docker main daemon runs as root and should be able to set any limits on its own.